# Catch 22: Create tag synonym from [drools-planner] to [optaplanner], but it's impossible to delete the invalid reverse tag first

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Drools Planner renamed to OptaPlanner about 2 years ago.

There is currently a tag synonym *suggestion* in the **wrong direction**:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/drools-planner/synonyms

The master should be [optaplanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optaplanner), of course.

I can't add the correct synonym because the inverse exists (SO prevents me). I can't delete the invalid synonym (which I created ironically), so I can't create the proper synonym.

Catch 22

Comment: @Deduplicator I tried adding the correct synonym but SO didn't accept it because the reverse exists.

Comment: I can't vote on my own wrongfull synonym suggestion, not even to downvote it. I can't delete it either.

Comment: Fixed that for you.